# tensorboard shows a SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to run tensorboard but it keeps showing the same error.

```
tensorboard --logdir=tensorflow/logdir
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed tensorflow-gpu by virtualenv.

Comment: That's a command to be typed at your operating system's command prompt, NOT in Python itself.

Answer (score 7):

You are running `tensorboard --logdir=tensorflow/logdir` from an interactive python shell or ipython/jupyter-notebook. As mentioned in the comment above, you need to run this command from the terminal. Alternatively, you can run the command from ipython/jupyter by putting the `!` at the beginning of the command, i.e by running `!tensorboard --logdir=tensorflow/logdir`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jupeter notebook or jupyter lab or google colab you should use the code:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir="logs"
```

if you are coding in terminal

```
tensorboard --logdir="logs"
```

this code will work well